# In Twitter Bootstrap 2, how can I get right columns to move to the top when shrinking the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a 2-column fluid layout in Twitter Bootstrap.  The left column is the main content (span10), and the right column is a sidebar for widgets (span2).  Currently, when resizing the browser window, Bootstrap responds by creating one column with the leftmost section on top, and the rightmost on bottom.  I'd like it the other way around.

This is the gist of my html:

```
<body>
  <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="content-row-1" class="row-fluid">
      <div id="mainContainer" class="span10"> Lots of content goes here </div>
      <div id="sidebar" class="span2"> Widgets   </div>
    </div>  <!-- content-row-1 -->
  </div>  <!-- content -->
</body>
```

Is there any way to have `mainContainer` on the left and widgets on the right in a wide window, but snap `sidebar` to the top when the window shrinks?

Comment: This is easy since bootstrap 3. See my answer below (this comment is here fore all bootstrap 3 users - scroll down)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question title to reflect that the question and answer are for TB2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Responded to a question much like this one today, you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386822/680398), what it basically came down to was shifting the flow of the sidebar by floating it to the right and compensating for the left margin of the content area and then resetting the float attribute of the sidebar with a `@media` query to accommodate the sidebar once again with its default value from the bootstrap stylesheet.

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

#sidebar {
    float:right;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #sidebar {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Here is a reworked demo from the previous question: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/YEUwN/2/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/YEUwN/2/show/).

Answer (score 32):

In bootstrap 3 this is done with grid column ordering
([see bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering))

Example

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

This will show the upper `div` behind the lower `div` if there is enough space. If the screen size is reduced the upper `div` will stay up.

Comment: The asker isn't using Bootstrap 3. They're using Bootstrap 2.

Comment: @greenie2600 Take a look at the second comment on the question. When i wrote this answer the question was not asking about bootstrap 2 either, but bootstrap in general.

Answer (score 5):

I come after the question is resolved with an extremely **simple way** to achieve this. No need for @media nor percentage:

- Place the div you want on top of the page for mobiles before the other div. In this case #sidebar comes before #mainContainer in your HTML code
- Give to #sidebar the class pull-right
- Give to #mainContainer the class pull-left
- Set margin-left for those 2 divs to 0

As a result you'll have your sidebar on the right for desktop and on top for mobiles.

Example:

```
--- HTML 

<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="content-row-1" class="row-fluid">
    <div id="sidebar" class="span2 pull-right"> Widgets   </div>
    <div id="mainContainer" class="span10 pull-left"> Lots of content goes here </div>
  </div>  <!-- content-row-1 -->
</div>  <!-- content -->

--- CSS

div#sidebar, div#mainContainer {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your parameters, just reverse the `sidebar` and `mainContainer` divs in the html source order and `float: right` each of them. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/3g8Bt/.

Comment: I can't set the width of the sidebar, as I am using a fluid layout. Also, using float:right breaks the grid.

Comment: @eterps--You should be able to switch a row's components from floating left (which I think is the default in bootstrap) to right. You might need to adjust some margin to make it all align with the grid. My width was just for an example of how to get the effect you want. The key is that you have to get the sidebar first in the source order to get it to stack above the container, and then push it right (if you want it right)--hence, right float. Maybe this will help: http://milespickens.com/blog/title/twitter-bootstap-moving-sidebar-to-the-right

Comment: +1 for the effort and the link. It was a nudge in the right direction, but @andres had the complete solution I was looking for.

Comment: To reverse the order in the markup as impacts on such things like SEO optimization and screen reader support. It is not at all a solution.

Comment: @feeela: That's why I said "depending on your parameters" in the beginning of my answer. Whether reversing the order for SEO or screen reader needs is relevant to one's parameters is up to the person designing, but my answer is still one solution to the problem of ordering the elements at a narrow screen width. So contrary to your statement, it is in fact a solution. If it doesn't meet the parameters for your design needs, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a super-simple solution that seems to work with at least a 2 column layout. Just create a new class for you markup and some simple CSS.

### HTML (Pulled from my Drupal .tpl)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9 pull-right re-order">
        <?php print $content['content']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 re-order">
        <?php print $content['sidebar']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.row-fluid .re-order {
    margin: 0;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 2.7624309392265194%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

This could probably be refined a bit more but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works great. 
Alternatively, sometimes things are complicated when you have several pieces of html need to appear at **anti-bootstrap** positions. It is also possible to solve it by creating duplicated html-snips, and use .visible-phone and .hidden-phone to control their show/hide.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 visible-phone">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab4</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span9">

      <p>
             Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus    commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </p>
</div>
<div class="span3 hidden-phone">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cullensun/6Cu3X/1/)