# Fluid or fixed grid system, in responsive design, based on Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout, fixed-width

I'm getting confused about the various options in the [twitter bootstrap grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html%5C), and how they go together.

To begin with, you can have an ordinary fixed `container`, or a `container-fluid`.

Then either one can include either an ordinary `row`, or a fluid row, `row-fluid`. That is, you can have a fixed container with a fluid row, or a container-fluid... with a fixed row?

Then on top of that, you can include the 'responsive' media queries, or not.

I am getting confused as to how these things interact. But let's start with one obvious example.

On [the examples page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) itself, there's what's presented as an example of both a [fixed grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and a [fluid grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

However, in my browser, on that example page itself -- both grids behave identically. Perhaps because the example page uses the optional responsive media queries?  In **both** grid examples, if I start gradually narrowing my browser window, the grid elements do *not* get gradually narrower -- once a certain (responsive) boundary width is reached, they snap to a smaller size, and again at further boundary widths.  But both the ordinary 'fixed' example AND the 'fluid' example behave exactly the same here -- so what the heck is the difference?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) is a better example of the fluid layout style?

Answer (score 444):

When you decide between fixed width and fluid width you need to think in terms of your ENTIRE page.  Generally, you want to pick one or the other, but not both.  The examples you listed in your question are, in-fact, in the same fixed-width page.  In other words, the Scaffolding page is using a fixed-width layout. The [fixed grid](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and [fluid grid](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) on the Scaffolding page are not meant to be examples, but rather the documentation for implementing fixed and fluid width layouts.

The proper fixed width example is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html).
The proper fluid width example is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html).

When observing the fixed width example, you should not see the content changing sizes when your browser is greater than 960px wide.  This is the maximum (fixed) width of the page.  Media queries in a fixed-width design will designate the minimum widths for particular styles.  You will see this in action when you shrink your browser window and see the layout snap to a different size.

Conversely, the fluid-width layout will *always* stretch to fit your browser window, no matter how wide it gets.  The media queries indicate when the styles change, but the width of containers are always a percentage of your browser window (rather than a fixed number of pixels).

The 'responsive' media queries are all ready to go. You just need to decide if you want to use a fixed width or fluid width layout for your page.

Previously, in bootstrap 2, you had to use `row-fluid` inside a fluid container and `row` inside a fixed container. With the introduction of bootstrap 3, `row-fluid` was removed, **do no longer use it**.

**EDIT**: As per the comments, some *jsFiddles* for:

- [fluid non-responsive layout](http://jsfiddle.net/5JECu/),
- [fluid responsive layout](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnEEa/),
- [fixed non-responsive layout](http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/ZR4zz/3/),
- [fixed responsive layout](http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/rdvaG/12/).

These fiddles are completely Bootstrap-free, based on pure CSS media queries, which makes them a good starting point, for anyone willing to craft similar solution without using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: hmm, okay, the docs seemed to me to suggest you could mix and match fluid and fixed, but I guess that's advanced usage I'm not ready for. :) I still don't understand how `responsive` changes both fixed and fluid respectively -- you can use responsive (or not) with both fixed and fluid, right? Can you explain how responsive effects them each?

Comment: the confusing thing to me remain that the 'proper fixed width' example DOES change sizes of columns as browser window changes (beause it's responsive?) And so does the proper fluid width example. But I guess the fluid width example does it continuously, and the fixed width responsive example does it in discrete jumps, as well as reaching a maximum size? Is that it?  How about fluid responsive vs not responsive?

Comment: You've got it.  In the fixed width layout, the columns change when the browser window reaches a width defined in a media query.  So when you have your window greater than 960px wide, it will stay at it's maximum width.  Then when you shrink your browser to 959px, it will snap to a new layout based on a media query that has a maximum width of 768px.  So because you are viewing a fixed-width layout, the columns *will not* change when your browser width is between 768 and 960.

Comment: And when you are viewing a fluid-width layout, the column sizes will *always* change to match your browser's width.  The layout itself will also change in accordance to the media queries, as with a fixed-width layout.

Comment: The most important thing to remember is that fixed width = pixels, and fluid width = percent.  

The responsiveness comes from all the fancy CSS rules defined in bootstrap-responsive.css, and those rules apply to both layouts.

Comment: i can't tell what the difference is between twitter bootstrap fluid responsive vs non-responsive though. maybe I just need to play with it more. The fluid already changes with window size, what's the responsive part when you have fluid responsive?

Comment: Ok, for fluid-responsive, do this:  Open the fluid example and maximize your window.  Observe how the navigation menu is a horizontal list.  Now slowly reduce the width of your browser.  At some point, the navigation bar will change so that a button appears, and when the button is clicked, the menu appears as vertical.  So with fluid, the only thing that changes is the *width* of the elements.  With a responsive design, you can change *any* css rule based on the width of the browser.  See my edited answer for some jsFiddle examples.

Comment: Did the JSFiddle Examples above help at all?

Comment: They did to me, any how :) Thanks a lot for this discussion!

Comment: Btw, why does the fixed width layout not contain a sidebar? It's equally usable there, isn't it?

Comment: @JonatanLittke The fixed width layout can absolutely include a sidebar.  My current project uses one now.  Just make sure it is within your `container-fluid` div, and assign it a spanX class.  I asked a sidebar related question that might help you here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386441/in-twitter-bootstrap-how-can-i-get-right-columns-to-move-to-the-top-when-shrink

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out when testing. I guess the docs are to blame (again? :0) - it does look like the fluid is the only one that can contain it. Thanks :)

Comment: super-helpful question, answer and discussion here, thanks a lot

Comment: @eterps - please, can you edit your answer and add all 4 combination with exact description of the design features for each one? Mean: fixed-normal, fixed-responsive, fluid-normal, fluid-responsive? This is an excellent post, but still don't understand fully what is the "fixed-responsive" design.

Comment: Hey @jm666, I added a couple more examples.  Fixed-responsive is almost exactly the same as fluid-responsive, only it uses pixel values for width instead of %.  So in a fixed-normal page, your widths will never change. You can shrink the browser as much as you want and the columns in the example will always remain 130px each.  

In the fixed-responsive example, You can stretch and shrink your browser window, and the columns will remain the same width until the window becomes less than 300px wide.  When that happens, the media query kicks in and applies the new css rules.

Comment: @eterps Thank you so much! I have a task where I need to lay out images in a grid. Each is about 300px wide. I want to use fluid version of bootstrap. I'm practicing the mobile first philosophy. so for 320px I'll show only 2 images, but as you increase the browser, more images will flow into view. This requires more breakpoints than bootstap uses: there is a break-point for each new image/row. Do you have any idea how to achieve this using bootstap. I've done something but I'd like to hear/see how you'd approach it. I'll probably use a max-width of 1800px after which things are centered. thnx!

Comment: Can you not have a fluid-row in a fixed layout? I don't why you can't.

Comment: You absolutely can mix fluid rows into a fixed layout. It's not common though, as having portions of the page behaving differently than others might cause confusion for users.  If you need to do it though, just override the pixel widths of the span tags with percentage values, or create your own % based div and style it to fit inside the Bootstrap scaffolding.

Comment: @eterps, with the examples you provided, are you saying if `px` is used as width unit, then use `fixed`. if `%` is used as width unit, then use `fluid`?

Comment: That is the convention used by Bootstrap.  YOU pick fixed or fluid. Once you do that BOOTSTRAP will set up px for fixed, and % for fluid.

Comment: So, a follow-up question on this: Using a fixed layout with a full-size header image behind your big site title a la Bootstrap - which size should I crop my image to?

Comment: Bootstrap will resize the img tag. So crop to the largest size you want.

Comment: Is there a way to “lock down” the fixed sizes? For instance, mine looks perfect at 1000px, but looks bad when it shrinks down. (That’s why I was using what I thought was a “fixed” layout.) Can you do that with bootstrap?

Comment: @eterps responded to this question off SO, but i'll put it here for future info: Sounds like you want fixed, but not responsive. Do not use bootstrap-responsive.css (or the equivalent less files). You can test this out very quickly by commenting out the last two lines of bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Thanks @eterps Please update the link for your answer at "The proper fluid width example is **here**." I get a 404 "There isn't a GitHub Page here." when going to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I fixed the links to point to the new location for the Bootstrap 2.3 docs.

Comment: Although not your point, this is the first time I've been shown the distinction between fluid and responsive.

Answer (score 21):

Interesting discussion. I was asking myself this question too. The main difference between fluid and fixed is simply that the fixed layout has a fixed width in terms of the whole layout of the website (viewport). If you have a 960px width viewport each colum has a fixed width which will never change.

The fluid layout behaves different. Imagine you have set the width of your main layout to 100% width. Now each column will only be calculated to it's relative size (i.e. 25%) and streches as the browser will be resized. So based on your layout purpose you can select how your layout behaves.

Here is [a good article about fluid vs. flex](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/).

Answer (score 7):

Source - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Pros

- Fixed-width layouts are much easier to use and easier to customize in terms of design.
- Widths are the same for every browser, so there is less hassle with images, forms, video and other content that are fixed-width.
- There is no need for min-width or max-width, which isn’t supported by every browser anyway.
- Even if a website is designed to be compatible with the smallest screen resolution, 800×600, the content will still be wide enough at a larger resolution to be easily legible.

Cons

- A fixed-width layout may create excessive white space for users with larger screen resolutions, thus upsetting “divine proportion,” the “Rule of Thirds,” overall balance and other design principles.
- Smaller screen resolutions may require a horizontal scroll bar, depending the fixed layout’s width.
- Seamless textures, patterns and image continuation are needed to accommodate those with larger resolutions.
- Fixed-width layouts generally have a lower overall score when it comes to usability.

Answer (score 6):

Fluid layout in Bootstrap 3.

Unlike Boostrap 2, Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a .container-fluid mixin to make a fluid container. The .container is a fixed width responsive grid layout. In a large screen, there are excessive white spaces in both sides of one's Web page content.

`container-fluid` is added back in Bootstrap 3.1

A fluid grid layout uses all screen width and works better in large screen. It turns out that it is easy to create a fluid grid layout using Bootstrap 3 mixins. The following line makes a fluid responsive grid layout:

.container-fixed;

The .container-fixed mixin sets the content to the center of the screen and add paddings. It doesn't specifies a fixed page width.

Another approach is to use [Eric Flowers' CSS style](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction)

```css
.my-fluid-container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people keep on saying that 'container-fluid' is not supported in Bootstrap 3, while it is. I've just double checked and in Bootstrap 3.1.0 it's clearly defined.

Comment: That's because it was removed in 3 [added back in 3.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/6273604601c58284f49b38ae4e52533b9689437c).

Answer (score -2):

you may use this - https://github.com/chanakyachatterjee/JSLightGrid ..JSLightGrid. have a look.. I found this one really very useful. Good performance, very light weight, all important browser friendly and fluid in itself, so you don't really need bootstrap for the grid.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10216606)

Comment: I agree .. but this is not a reference to the answer , this is a link to the plugin , where the the files can be downloaded, I guess I cannot attach files with answer here..