# How to create a dynamic width column in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

How do you use Twitter Bootstrap to create a table-like list structure, where some columns take as much space, as required to accommodate the widest element of that column, and a single column takes the remaining space?

For example:

```
Id    |Name     |Email address                
100001|Joe      |MamiePVillalobos@teleworm.us
100   |Christine|ChristineJWilliams@dayrep.com
1001  |John     |JohnLMiley@dayrep.com
```

the **Id column** takes just enough space to accommodate the 100001 id, which is the longest id.

The **Name column** takes just enough space to accommodate the name Christine.

The **Email column** takes the remaining space.

Comment: Tables where designed to display data like that. Why wouldn't you use one ? If you don't, do you really require the rows to be rows or just for appearance (e.g. make 3 column divs, floating left)?

Comment: This is a very simplified example. What I am looking for is a layout mechanism like Bootstrap's scaffolding system, only that I need some columns to be in variable width according to the content. I considered the float left alternative you suggest, but that means not using Boostrap.

Comment: Elad as far as i understood the documentation there is no variable length. In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/ and in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/rdvaG/12/ are demos of a responsive design. But it wraps the column into the next line. As far as i understood your requirements you would like to say col1: width: auto, col2: width auto and col2: width remaining. See my update below

Comment: If Bootstrap doesn't do it, why force it ? The grid is not meant to do that. If you really don't want to use the table, you can still cook something like [that jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/SDAZP/2/) - but the `<table>` is what HTML has for your problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Table like structure using the old table tag

Just kidding - or am i not.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr><th>Id</th>     <th>Name</th>      <th>Email address</th></tr>
  <tr><td>100001</td> <td>Joe</td>       <td>MamiePVillalobos@teleworm.us</td></tr>
  <tr><td>100</td>    <td>Christine</td> <td>ChristineJWilliams@dayrep.com</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1001</td>   <td>John</td>      <td>JohnLMiley@dayrep.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

### Using the grid system

In the documentation about the [bootstrap grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) i could not find any auto-width building blocks. Everything out of the box has a certain width and a fixed number of columns:

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span2">ID</div>
      <div class="span2">Name</div>
      <div class="span8">E-Mail</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2">100001</div>
      <div class="span2">Joe</div>
      <div class="span8">MamiePVillalobos@teleworm.us</div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="span2">100</div>
      <div class="span2">Christine</div>
      <div class="span8">ChristineJWilliams@dayrep.com</div>
    </div>
```

Therefore i assume that you have to build your own version for a 3-column-table with auto-size.

In my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CG6CT/7/) the grid-column wraps if the space is to narrow or, if the space is too wide, the columns are stretched.

### Update with creative markup

I updated my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CG6CT/7/) with a custom class. The creative markup comes close to what you are looking for

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="spanFl">100000001 <br />
        100
      </div>
      <div class="spanFl">Joe <br/>
          Christine
      </div>
      <div class="spanFl">MamiePVillalobos@teleworm.us <br />
        ChristineJWilliams@dayrep.com
      </div>
  </div>
```

#### Using css-3 display table

On [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/) i found an article using css-3 `display:table` to set up a table like layout. Unless you use three divs for each row it does not solve row wrapping issues.

```
#content {  
    display: table;  
}  
#mainContent {  
    display: table-cell;  
    width: 620px;  
    padding-right: 22px;  
}  
aside {  
    display: table-cell;  
    width: 300px;  
}
```

### Bootstrap responsive design

As far as i understood the [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) there is no built-in soultion for a 3-column layout with auto and remaining width. To Quote the responsive design page on bootstrap: "Use media queries responsibly and only as a start to your mobile audiences. For larger projects, do consider dedicated code bases and not layers of media queries."

Could you elaborate more why you can not use a table?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use bootstrap `.span` as columns, and `.row-fluid` inside each column to make lines - instead of your creative markup option ? Would be lots of markup, but still proper.

Comment: Did you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/m7wd5/4/ 
For shorter text it works fine (see version 3). For long text this leads to wrapping trouble

Comment: documentation for bootstrap grid system is no longer available.

Answer (score 10):

As others said, you should use regular tables where they make sense.
Also, CSS3 display:table can be a good solution.

Depending on the use case, there is a different solution you could consider:
https://github.com/donquixote/bootstrap-autocolumns/blob/master/bootstrap-autocolumns.css
This is a piece of CSS that adds "col-sm-auto" in addition to "col-sm-1", "col-sm-5" etc.

(Atm, I would recommend to just copy this to a custom css file and adjust to your needs.)

#### Example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-auto">Left</div>
  <div class="col-xs-auto-right">Right</div>
  <div class="col-middle">Middle</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wzqz/

#### Idea

- .col-*-auto floats to the left, with the typical padding, but without any explicit width setting.
- .col-*-auto-right floats to the right instead.
- .col-middle has display:table, which prevents it from floating around the other elements.
- Use "xs", "sm", "md", "lg" to target specific screen widths.

#### Limitations

The left/right columns will expand to full width, if you fill them with long text. Better use them for fixed-width stuff like images.

The middle column will only take the full available width if it has enough content in it.

Comment: Also if on the second row you have a content of different width, your table cells won't be aligned to a single column of a fixed width.

Comment: I read that `overflow:hidden;` is another way to prevent content from wrapping under the floats, and I'd say this is the preferable way.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't need to *limit* the column size, you can just disable the width.

```
<span class="col-xs-1" style="width: inherit !important; ">unknown ...</span>
```

I need the bootstrap definition for the other column's properties (padding, height, etc.), so I added a col definition, but a small unit (col-xs-1).

notes:

- the "!important" clause might be dropped (i'm not sure)
- In my project the texts are known to be small anyway.

Comment: Thank you!! I love it, fixed it right up for me, nothing else worked.

Answer (score -1):

Well according To [bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)
you can apply `table-responsive` css class to the table element and make it responsive. What I observed was it actually makes scroll-able.