# CSS: scrollable table misaligned Columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table scrollable with a fixed header with hover effect. I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928369/html-css-table-misaligned-columns) to set my css file. I always got misaligned columns:
`here is my Plnker demo:`[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8zv2hAxm2Bmfqufv67Pt?p=preview)

any help please ?

update:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `display: block` rule breaks table alignment.

Where you have:

```
.hoverTable tbody, .hoverTable thead { display: block; width: calc(100% - 17px); }
```

Remove that rule:

```
.hoverTable tbody, .hoverTable thead { width: calc(100% - 17px); }
```

You also have 9 th elements and 10 td elements. Place an empty `th` in at the end of the `thead` to equalize them.

Comment: thanks. but I think I have to keep `display: block` because I need the make the table scrollable, right ? I removed it and my table became not scrollable

Comment: In modern browsers, you can make the whole table a scrollable container and use `position:sticky` to make the heading cells to stay at its top, like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/NFcutk7xKgXTKoSps21o?p=preview

Comment: Then you should use a different schema, like a Bootstrap grid. Tables are extremely finicky, and you will go way out into the weeds trying to equalize scrolling and also alignment, and wind up spending 10x longer than just doing it with Bootstrap or a similar grid library using divs.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn has a good approach if you are not supporting legacy browsers.

Comment: thanks for both of you. I applied what @IlyaStreltsyn put in his demo, and i still get the same issue. I put 2 screenshots in my question to show the problem I want to solve.

Comment: just to clarify: the misalignment is solved. but the width of the table is not 100%

Comment: The problem you are having is that `display: block` does not enforce vertical alignment between columns like `display: table` (default) does. You will need to remove display block and work around the remaining layout quirks, or use a non-table responsive layout to insure correct display across all browsers. The `sticky` option also requires removing `display: block` to render correctly.