# navbar is not resizing when you adjust browser size

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am doing ruby rails devloping , using navbar from twitter bootstrap

but my navbar is nto resizing on firefox if i am trying to reduce the windows size..

anyone know how to fix it??

Mycode:

```
%body
  %header.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
    %nav.navbar-inner
      .container
        = render 'mynavbar'
```

Comment: A good question will include relevant code.

Comment: i just directly using the stuffs from twitter bootstrap

Comment: that may be the case but we need code to duplicate the issue and instead of making everyone re-create what we think you mean, it's best if the person asking the question just gives it to us to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are including the responsive.css file and are using the .container-fluid class in your html.

See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: In case you don't know the difference between fluid and responsive : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9780333/1478467 . So I don't think that the `.container-fluid` is necessary.