# Bootstrap: how do I change the width of the container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to develop a website with the fixed container class, but now the client wants the website to be 1000px width and not 1170px. I don't use the .less files.

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: Refer to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/twitter-bootstrap-fluid-vs-fixed-then-add-in-responsive-how-does-it-all-fit-t), i think your problem will be solved by [Fixed-only fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/ZR4zz/3/) in that answer.

Comment: @prem, tx but i don't get the example as it doesn't use any of the bootstrap classes like span's or container. All i think i need for this project is to set the max of the container to 940px with the responsive bootstrap.

Comment: @alex I simply tried `<div class="container col-12"> ... </div>` and that widened the container. That was the quick way to fix it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Go to the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) section on Bootstrap site and choose the size you prefer. You'll have to set `@gridColumnWidth` and `@gridGutterWidth` variables.

For example: `@gridColumnWidth = 65px` and `@gridGutterWidth = 20px` results on a `1000px` layout.

Then download it.

Comment: one can't reach exact 1000px container by changing gridColumnWidth and gridGutterWidth variables...                               because (12*(gridColumnWidth) + 12(gridGutterWidth)) doesnot equals 1000. And so only i gave that solution. Is that correct?

Comment: Theoretically, there are infinite combinations that match 1000px. An example: 12*65 + 11*20 = 1000 (there are only 11 gutters between columns).

Comment: huh! i really didn't recognize the simple thing... anyways your's was the apt solution.

Comment: Thanks for your post, it was helpful ;) Just a note: Practically there would be exactly 7 solutions using full pixels for 1000px width. (colum widths 10, 21, 32, 43, 54, 65 and 76)

Comment: @dfherr I don't know what you exactly mean when you say "practically", but please keep in mind that CSS supports decimal values for pixels. Therefore, there are infinite solutions. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units

Comment: @albertedevigo though css does accept decimals, according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected browsers do not necessarily respect them. So only in theory there are infinite solutions. That's what i meant with "practically". One step further there is also the limitation of physical pixels on the used display.

Comment: From what I can see, there is no `@grid-column-width` variable anymore. I had to change `@container-tablet`, `@container-desktop`, `@container-large-desktop` variables.

Answer (score 277):

Here is the solution :

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 970px;
    }
}
```

The advantage of doing this, versus customizing Bootstrap as in [@Bastardo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19595984/25507) answer, is that it doesn't change the Bootstrap file.  For example, if using a CDN, you can still download most of Bootstrap from the CDN.

Comment: Most answers neglect CDN. Your answer is a perfect solution.

Comment: It's perfect for people who are using the CDN. Modifying the LESS (when 4 arrives, the SASS) at build time is perfect for people hosting their own Bootstrap CSS. However, modifying a custom LESS (or SASS) imported after the one provided means you can upgrade the underlying LESS without (usually) doing a diff.

Comment: I know this is really late, but given containers tend to be bigger now if you add width:auto to the above code you can make containers bigger than their 1170 max.

Answer (score 21):

You are tying one had behind your back saying that you won't use the LESS files.  I built my first Twitter Bootstrap theme using 2.0, and I did everything in CSS -- creating an override.css file.  It took days to get things to work correctly.

Now we have 3.0.  Let me assure you that it takes less time to learn LESS, which is pretty straight forward if you're comfortable with CSS, than doing all of those crazy CSS overrides.  Making changes like the one you want is a piece of cake.

In Bootstrap 3.0, the container class controls the width, and all of the contained styles adjust to fill the container.  The container width variables are at the bottom of the variables.less file.

```
// Container sizes
// --------------------------------------------------

// Small screen / tablet
@container-tablet:            ((720px + @grid-gutter-width));

// Medium screen / desktop
@container-desktop:           ((940px + @grid-gutter-width));

// Large screen / wide desktop
@container-lg-desktop:        ((1020px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

Some sites either don't have enough content to fill the 1020 display or you want a narrower frame for aesthetic reasons.  Because BS uses a 12-column grid I use a multiple like 960.

Comment: Works, but: variables names are `@container-sm`, `@container-md` and `@container-lg` (now)

Answer (score 20):

@mcbjam already gave this answer but here's a bit more explanation.

You can easily make the change using a media query in your CSS file without downloading BS. I just did this and it works beautifully.

The media query's "min-width" value will tell CSS to change the width of your container to 1000px *only* on screens larger than 1200px (or whatever width you choose to include there). This preserves the responsiveness of your site, so when the screen size jumps below that value (smaller monitor, tablet, smartphone, etc.), your site will still adjust to fit the smaller screens.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

For bootstrap 4 if you are using Sass here is the variable to edit

```
// Grid containers
//
// Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```

To override this variable I declared $container-max-widths without the !default in my .sass file before importing bootstrap.

Note : I only needed to change the xl value so I didn't care to think about breakpoints.

Comment: [@kaizoku-gambare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4914853), you can modify your answer, since it's [still valid in Bootstrap 5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/containers/#css). The only thing that's new is another breakpoint called `xxl`.

Answer (score 12):

Set your own content container class with 1000px width property and then use [container-fluid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) boostrap class instead of container.

Works but might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

Use a wrapper selector and create a container that has a 100% width inside of that wrapper to encapsulate the entire page.

```
<style>#wrapper {width: 1000px;} 
#wrapper .container {max-width: 100%; display: block;}</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">....
```

Now the maximum width is set to 1000px and you need no less or sass.

Comment: It's work, Just put your code within container class div.

Answer (score 8):

In bootstrap, Just add this to your .CSS file

```
.container {
   max-width: 70% !important;/*Set your own width %; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Container sizes

```
@container-large-desktop
(1140px + @grid-gutter-width) -> (970px + @grid-gutter-width)
```

in section Container sizes, change **`1140`** to **`970`**

I hope its help you.

---

thank you for your correct.
link for customize bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add container to sticky navbar ;

Answer (score -6):

Add these piece of CSS in your css styling. Its better to add this after the bootstrap css file is added in order to overwrite the same.

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}`
```