# how do I change the width of the container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to develop a website with the fixed container class, but now i wants the website to be 960px width and not 1170px. I don't use the .less files.

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to compile it yourself, you can get a [customized version from the official website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) with necessary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your bootstrap.css

```
.container
{
min-width: 960px !important;
max-width: 960px !important;
width: 960px !important;
}
```

Maybe not all are required, but just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom fixed width container..

```
.container-fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

And use this instead of `.container`. Here is a working demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/71142

Answer (score 0):

As Answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884102/bootstrap-how-do-i-change-the-width-of-the-container#answer-28290519)
- Its best to extend the bootstrap(.min).css rather than editing the file your self if you are using a CDN customizing the core css isn't an option.