# What is the difference between bootstrap fixed and fluid layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Difference between bootstrap fixed and fluid layout?

http://jquery-simplified.blogspot.in/2013/05/twitter-bootstrap-default-grid-system.html

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/twitter-bootstrap-fluid-vs-fixed-then-add-in-responsive-how-does-it-all-fit-t

Answer (score 1):

The fixed layout will always be a certain width, and when you resize your browser, it will not adjust. The fluid layout will adjust to the width of the browser.