# understanding on making websites responsive with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using twitter bootstrap enduring difficulties arises when overwriting it's codes to end up in responsiveness.Recently i used t bootstrap like -

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">

-------- all contents start here
```

when i re-size my browser i see that unexpectedly contents as well as everything re-sizing itself, despite of having fixed width(in px) for container class as we know bootstrap css.
how it's happening when i know that to have responsiveness properly contents will be under these codes -

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12"> 
.......................
```

as these all imply width according to percentage, so it makes sense to be responsive in all windows and mobile devices.

So is it all right that whether i do fixed width design by twitter bootstrap, still it's properly responsive? and if yes how twitter bootstrap does this as having bit difficulties in understanding those css files.

Comment: Good explanation here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/fluid-or-fixed-grid-system-in-responsive-design-based-on-twitter-bootstrap?lq=1

Comment: Still not clear, need follow up understanding as it's not directly written

Comment: 1.: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/topics

2.: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap-3/topics