# bootstrap giving extra width on left hand side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating my first site using bootstrap, and as its a joomla site its version 2.3

I am having some problems getting going
here is the code so far:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row logobar">
<div class="span12">
<div class="logoholder">
<img src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/open-plan-design-logo.jpg" alt="Open Plan Design Logo " />
</div>
</div>
<!-- row --></div>....
```

and the css

```
body {
    background:#231f21;
    background-color:#DCDBDB;
    color:#fff;
}

.container {
    background-color:yellow;
}

.logoholder{
    width:499px;
    margin:0 auto;
}


.logobar {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

At reduced screen widths everything looks fine - the image is centered, and reduces in size

However, at full width the image is not exactly centered, and there is an odd bit of green (from .logobar) sticking out at the left. If I take out the .row then the green disappears but of course nothing is resonsive

I guess I am doing something wrong...

you can see what I mean here  www.opd.ee-web.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `row` to `row-fluid` which will remove this negative `margin`.

```
<div class="row-fluid logobar">
```

Documentation [[1](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)]. 
More info [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/fluid-or-fixed-grid-system-in-responsive-design-based-on-twitter-bootstrap)].

Answer (score 1):

The elements with `.row` have a negative margin applied to ensure and contained `.span` elements are correctly aligned.

You can remove this negative margin with some custom css, but that is likely to cause more problems.

The ideal solution is to simple move the `logobar` to the `span` level.

```
<div class="span12 logobar">
```

Comment: @maxelcat please note that with your current approach on low resolutions (< 500px wide) the `container` will become smaller than the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your custom css file

```
body .row{
    margin-left:0 !important;
}
```