# Difference between container vs container-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers

Whats is difference between container and container-fluid in Bootstrap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fluid or fixed grid system, in responsive design, based on Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780333/fluid-or-fixed-grid-system-in-responsive-design-based-on-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the documentation? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container

> Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.
>
> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.