# Responsive Bootsrap Design: Priority of stacked Divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying the CSS-Framework Bootstrap and I have a question.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzAUz/

Let's say I have a div, with 3 equal divs inside of it:

```
<div id="main" class="row">
<div id="columnleft" class="span4">LEFT</div>
<div id="MainContent" class="span4">Content</div>
<div id="columnrigh" class="span4">Right</div>
</div>
```

So what happens, when you use Bootstrap, is that as soon as the windows get smaller, the Divs are stacked in this priority:
1. Left
2. Content
3. Right

But it makes sense, to put the content first.

Does anyone know how can insert priorities when using the bootstrap-responsive.css?

Thank you very much in advance.

KG,
George

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this.
One would be:
Start at the mobile size, and design "mobile first". That would make your small screen stuff easy, and then you could add additional classes to those containers to accommodate the larger screen sizes.

Another option:
Plan for mobile, and see if you can't either hide/convert your elements in smaller screen sizes to something more mobile friendly. ie...your left stack of nav links become a select menu in mobile; thus, only taking up a single line of real estate.

My preference is to use javascript, and convert left, and top navigation into a show/hide element (button) in mobile size. That way, I've just a logo and button in the top of my UI, and content immediately following.

Comment: Haha... yes... you gave me an excellent idea. I could just use the class "visible:desktop" and everytime the window gets smaller, the left column disappears and the content is shown first... I'm not sure if you meant this...

Comment: I did mean that. But not display:none... Every bit of content/functionality is available, regardless of screen size. What I meant was: In mobile, I don't show the left content in the same way as I do the main content; however, I tend to design from mobile up. Not mobile as an afterthought. If it's a left nav...it can be displayed as a dropdown(or a button/js interface), and not a UL. If it's content on the left, I'd stack them Main, Left, Right...and use the CSS in tablet/desktop to make it L/M/R

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way in Bootstrap 2, but if you were to move to Bootstrap 3, you can control column ordering. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering for details.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Googled for column ordering and found this article, which explains what you said in more detail: [Link](http://mattduchek.com/differences-between-bootstrap-v2-3-and-v3-0/)

Thanks a lot. You have any idea, when bootstrap 3 will come out? (I know the RC is already available, I mean the steady version)

Comment: Final (3.0.0) came out last month some time. They are already working towards 3.0.1, so you should be safe to use it if you want to move up.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively upgrade to bootstrap 3 if you can, as @Sean suggested, but if you can't right now, some of these answers may help:

[In Twitter Bootstrap 2, how can I get right columns to move to the top when shrinking the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386441/in-twitter-bootstrap-how-can-i-get-right-columns-to-move-to-the-top-when-shrink)